# Is this a secure way to open an iframe to a PHP proxy script?

Tags: javascript, php, security, proxy

We are using a tool provided by a trusted third-party on our website. The basic premise is:

1. user clicks a link
2. modal window opens which contains an iframe whose source is on the third-party's website
3. the user interacts with the tool, and when they're finished, an iframe message is sent back to us
4. we receive the iframe message and close the modal and do whatever else we want

That all works fine. However, we also use third-party screen-recording services, which often times have trouble recording the interaction inside the iframe, since it's loaded from an external domain. In these cases when we watch a recording of a user's interaction, the iframe will just be a big blank splotch. Note that some screen recording providers do have ways to work inside a third-party iframe, but I don't want to be stuck with just those providers in case they change prices etc.

So, I'm thinking about using a PHP proxy that lives on our domain as a go-between. That way, the iframe source points to our own domain, and the user's interaction within should be recorded just fine.

Unfortunately I'm not the world's foremost expert on javascript + iframe + PHP proxy security. **Does the below code have any security holes that need to be fixed?**

I know that loading the third-party content in this way is one potential issue - however, this is a trusted source so I'm not at all worried about anything devious from them. I'm more concerned about a hacker trying to do irritating things with my proxy script or something..

Here are the relevant code snippets..

1. My javascript that creates the iframe on user-click, it receives the `href` of the link that was clicked:

```
    window.openProxiedIframe = href => {
        let url = new URL('https:' + href);
        let queryString = "?";
        for (const [key, value] of url.searchParams) {
            queryString = `${queryString}${key}=${value}&`;
        }
        let proxyURL = "https://www.example.com/proxy.php" + queryString;
        if ( jQuery("#designTool").length && jQuery("#designTool").hasClass("ui-dialog-content") ) {
            jQuery("#designTool").dialog("destroy");
            jQuery("#designTool").remove();
        }
        jQuery(`<div id='designTool'><iframe style='height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0px; border: none;' src='${proxyURL}' /></div>`).appendTo("body").dialog({
            modal: true,
            title:"Design Your Item"
        });
    };
```

2. My PHP proxy (proxy.php):

```
// it's not important what a and b are, what matters is that they are required, so
// any legit request will have them. Also note that example.com here is really
// a third-party domain, not us. Again, the third-party is trusted, and
// I hardcoded their domain to prevent anyone from trying to force this
// script to open some other page on the internet
if ( isset( $_REQUEST["a"] ) && isset( $_REQUEST["b"] ) ) {
    $url = "https://www.example.com/designTool?a=" . urlencode($_REQUEST["a"]) . "&b=" . urlencode($_REQUEST["b"]);
    $contents = file_get_contents( $url );
    echo $contents;
}
```

3. Last, the javascript that listens for the iframe message telling us that the user has completed their design:

```
// usingProxy is defined elsewhere as true if we are using the proxy.php script.
// In case we are NOT using the proxy, I check that the origin is
// the third-party domain. Otherwise, I check that the origin is our domain
window.addEventListener("message", function(event){
    if (
        event.origin === "https://www.example.com" ||
        (
            usingProxy &&
            (window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host).indexOf(event.origin) === 0
        )
    ) {
        // ok then, this is our message, go ahead and do stuff with it, close the modal, and stop listening for more messages
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not easy to do correctly. If the web page you're proxying contains any URLs that refer back to the site, you'd need to redirect them all to your proxy as well.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. In this situation there are no references to any other site. The proxied page is a stand-alone design tool (written in React) that triggers the `iframe` `message` when the user clicks to complete their design. Testing so far has shown that images etc load correctly in the proxied-version of the tool

Comment: Not references to other sites, references to the SAME site. E.g. if the web page contains `<img>` elements with URLs that point to the same site.

Comment: gotcha, I misunderstood at first, see my edit to my comment :)

Comment: Also FWIW I'm pretty sure all images etc on the design tool are coded to load from the host domain (so like `src='https://www.example.com/whatever.jpg'`. I suppose that's why all images are loading fine when I test the proxied version

Comment: If you use a proxy, why not get rid of the iframe?  Both serve the purpose of allowing you to display foreign content on your web site, although one fetches the foreign content from the browser, and the other from your server.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few potential security issues with the given code:

- Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities: The window.openProxiedIframe function does not appear to sanitize the href parameter before inserting it into the proxyURL variable. This could potentially allow an attacker to inject malicious code into the proxyURL variable by manipulating the href parameter. This could lead to a Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) vulnerability, which would allow an attacker to execute arbitrary code in the context of the victim's browser. To mitigate this issue, you should sanitize the href parameter before inserting it into the proxyURL variable.
- Insecure use of file_get_contents: The proxy.php script uses the file_get_contents function to retrieve the contents of the third-party URL. This function is generally not recommended for use in a production environment due to the potential for remote code execution vulnerabilities. To mitigate this issue, you should consider using a more secure alternative such as cURL or HTTP requests with the http_build_url function.
- Lack of origin validation: The window.addEventListener function does not appear to validate the origin of the incoming message. This means that an attacker could potentially send a message from an arbitrary origin, and the listener would still process it. To mitigate this issue, you should ensure that the origin of the incoming message is properly validated before processing the message.
- Lack of content validation: The window.addEventListener function does not appear to validate the content of the incoming message. This means that an attacker could potentially send a malicious message that could compromise the security of the website. To mitigate this issue, you should ensure that the content of the incoming message is properly validated before processing it.

In general, it's important to carefully consider the security implications of using an iframe and PHP proxy, and take steps to mitigate any potential vulnerabilities.